# Множества как индекс в массиве C++

Tags: множества, строки, c++

Имеется следующий код:

```
enum colors { red,green,blue };//дано множество 
int myArray[colors::blue];//и массив
string strColor="Red";//Далее пользователь вводит строку, например
```

Точно помню, что в паскале можно было провернуть что-то вроде этого:

```
myArray[strColor]=...;
```

Comment: Либо я что то не понятно написал, либо никто не знает ответа. Напишите пожалуйста если мой вопрос неясен.

Comment: int myArray[colors::blue]; - в данном контексте это будет массив из 2х неинициализированных (т.е. со случайными значениями) int. Так писать не надо.

Comment: enum это, кстати, не множество, а перечисление.

Answer (score 5):

В C++ так нельзя. Соответственно, нужно городить либо хардкод на условиях, либо пользоваться промежуточным словарем map<string,int>.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте прослойку для преобразования string -> enum.

Например так:

```
enum colors { red, green, blue }

colors colorFromString(const std::string& str)
{
    static const std::map<std::string, colors> allColors
    {
        { "red",   colors::red   },
        { "green", colors::green },
        { "blue",  colors::blue  }
    };

    auto founded = allColors.find(str);
    if (founded == allColors.cend())
    {
        // Элемент не найден
        // Здесь необходимо как-то обработать ошибку
        // Например:
        throw std::runtime_error("Not found element " + str);
    }

    return founded->second;
}
```

Дальше можете делать так, как вы и хотели:

```
std::string strColor = "red";
myArray[colorFromString(strColor)]=...;
```

PS: Если будете использовать исключения - не забывайте их перехватывать.